# Is there any way we can check if certain action will bring in external links?

Tags: excel, vba

We develop customized tools using Excel VBA. One daily struggle is the users will not follow the best practice and bring external links into the workbook, which they will need those removed eventually. I'm wondering if there is any function/code we can incorporate into the workbook to detect if any external links brought in after certain actions, such as move in a tab or copy in some formulas from other workbook? Any advice will be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Please note, StackOverflow focuses on answering *objective* questions, not subjective questions. Tips on how to possibly do something fall into the `Too Broad` category and related questions are often Closed. If you would please edit your post to be more objective, that will most likely get you further on this forum.

Comment: To add to the discussion piece of this post, have you tried using a `change event` where the cell does soemthing like breaks hyperlinks?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.linksources